# re.sub in python do not always substitute the string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

When I try to substitute a string with another string, it does not always happen with re.sub method.

```
sentence = '<date>2004/12/01</date>T09:38:27+01:00'+
           'Wed, <date>2012/9/05</date> 10:55:17 UTC %3C%3C%3C'

time_identifier = u'(?<=[\s\.,T])([\d]{2}[:]{1}[\d]{2}([:]{1}[\d]{2})*[\s\.,+]*(UTC|GMT|CEST|EDT|IST|BST)*(\d\d:\d\d)*)(?=[\s\.,T]|\Z)|'\
                  u'(?<=\A)([\d]{2}[:]{1}[\d]{2}([:]{1}[\d]{2})*[\s\.,+]*(UTC|GMT|CEST|EDT|IST|BST)*(\d\d:\d\d)*)(?=[\s\.,T]|\Z)'
time = re.search(time_identifier, sentence, flags=re.U|re.I)
    if time:
        try:
            sentence = re.sub(time.groups()[0], '<time>%s</time>'%time.groups()[0], sentence, flags=re.U|re.I)
        except:
            sentence = re.sub(time.groups()[4], '<time>%s</time>'%time.groups()[4], sentence, flags=re.U|re.I)
```

For the above provided example, I expect the output of the sentences to be

```
<date>2004/12/01</date>T<time>09:38:27+01:00<time>
Wed, <date>2012/9/05</date> <time>10:55:17 UTC</time> %3C%3C%3C
```

But the re.sub method do not replace "09:38:27+01:00" in the original sentence by

```
"<time>09:38:27+01:00</time>"
```

Can anyone please clarify the reason for this?

Comment: If you print `time.groups()[0]`, you'll see that your regex isn't grabbing the `09:38:27+01:00`.  I have no idea why (and I'm not about to try to sort through that monstrous re and figure it out).

Comment: I don't have time to look into your issue but I highly recommend http://www.regex101.com/ to design your expressions, should help to some degree.

Comment: You really want to simplify that expression; `[:]{1}` is just a very verbose way of saying `:`; e.g. match exactly one colon. In the same vein, there is no need to wrap a `\d` in brackets (`[\d]` is the same as `\d`). And `\d\d` is slightly shorter than `\d{2}`.

Comment: @ Martijn: I have built the regex with many other date formats in mind. I will definitely change them

Comment: @mgilson: Testing on my pc, the regex captures 09:38:27+01:00, but just does not tag

Comment: @user1514027: it doesn't tag because of the issue with the plus sign (it is a special character inside a pattern). See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expressions are terribly over-complicated. The following is a simplification that matches the exact same patterns:

```
time_identifier = u'(?:(?<=[\s\.,T])|\A)(\d\d:\d\d(:\d\d)*[\s\.,+]*(UTC|GMT|CEST|EDT|IST|BST)*(\d\d:\d\d)*)(?=[\s\.,T]|\Z)'
```

Your time strings are not being matched because of the look-ahead assertion (the `(?=[\s\.,T]|\Z)` part); it limits matches to anything that is followed by whitespace, a full stop, a comma, a letter `T` or the end of the string. Your first string is followed immediately by `Wed` in the sentence; there is no whitespace.

The following `sentence` value *does* match:

```
sentence = ('<date>2004/12/01</date>T09:38:27+01:00 '
            'Wed, <date>2012/9/05</date> 10:55:17 UTC %3C%3C%3C')
```

Note the extra space after the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here. First, your very complicated pattern. Second, you can't do something like:

```
re.sub('09:38:27+01', "<time>'09:38:27+01'</time>, s)
```

because due to the plus sign the string `s` doesn't match the pattern (I'm assuming that your groups contain the proper times) so that part of the string won't be tagged. That answers your question.

The following works with your sample data (although maybe I've over-simplified the initial pattern):

```
p = '((?:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\+\\d{2}:\\d{2})|(?:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} UTC|GMT|CEST|EDT|IST|BST))'
result = re.findall(p, s)
print result
['09:38:27+01:00', '10:55:17 UTC']
r0 = result[0]
r0 = re.sub('\+', r'\+', r0)
s = re.sub(r0, "<time>%s</time>" % result[0], s)
s = re.sub(result[1], "<time>%s</time>" % result[1], s)
print s
'<date>2004/12/01</date>T<time>09:38:27+01:00</time>Wed, <date>2012/9/05</date> <time>10:55:17 UTC</time> %3C%3C%3C'
```

Hope it helps.